# How to navigate back to the page after two fetch functions are executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem where i use fetch two times in my function. If i execute the function without `useNavigate` both the fetch functions are executed properly, but with it only one of the fetch functions are executed. Im wondering if it has something to do with async

this is without using `Navigate` which works just fine

```
updateTrahcan = (messagedata) => {
        fetch(
            "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
            {
                method: "PUT",
                body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
            ).then(() => {
                fetch(
                    "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
                    {
                        method: "DELETE",
                        body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                        headers:{
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                    }
                )
            })
    }
```

and this is using `Navigate` where only one of the fetch functions are executed

```
updateTrahcan = (messagedata) => {
        fetch(
            "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
            {
                method: "PUT",
                body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
            ).then(() => {
                fetch(
                    "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
                    {
                        method: "DELETE",
                        body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                        headers:{
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                    }
                )
            }).then(() =>{
                 this.props.navigation(0);
            )
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this instead

```
updateTrahcan = async (messagedata) => {
    await fetch(
        "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
        {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
        )
     await fetch(
                "url" + (this.state.MessageEdit.id) + ".json",
                {
                    method: "DELETE",
                    body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            )
        })
        this.props.navigation(0);
        
}
```

hope this will do the job for you.